# OneNote API : PATCH request for topmost object

Tags: objective-c, onenote, office365-restapi

I am trying to figure out how to update my page - I need to replace everything inside a `<body>` tag always.

OneNote API says:

> The following elements do not support any PATCH actions:
>   - img or object (absolutely positioned) 
>   - meta, head
>   - tr, tda, span, any style tags
>
> **Note:** Absolutely positioned div, img, or object elements are direct children of the page body that define style=position:absolute.

Ok, that's clear. So I can't replace the `<object>` that does not have an ID, because if it doesn't it either should be part of `<div>` with id or it belongs to topmost div.

Here is my page's content:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en-US">
<head>
    <title>image and PDF 2</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body data-absolute-enabled="true" style="font-family:Calibri;font-size:11pt">
    <div id="div:{cfaf2831-c9e3-4b68-99ac-c4fc0bac0937}{32}" data-id="_default" style="position:absolute;left:48px;top:120px;width:624px">
        <p id="p:{cfaf2831-c9e3-4b68-99ac-c4fc0bac0937}{38}" style="margin-top:2.8pt;margin-bottom:2.8pt"> SOME TEXT HERE <br />
        </p>
        <object data-attachment="pdf-sample.pdf" type="application/pdf" data="https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/me/notes/resources/0-3329938c15524891836ef46f570c17ce!1-6481EB8A1188E91C!389/$value" />
        <img id="img:{cfaf2831-c9e3-4b68-99ac-c4fc0bac0937}{42}" alt="Image" src="https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/me/notes/resources/0-dfd3e39146d4425b974a71479787845f!1-6481EB8A1188E91C!389/$value" data-src-type="image/jpeg" data-fullres-src="https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/me/notes/resources/0-dfd3e39146d4425b974a71479787845f!1-6481EB8A1188E91C!389/$value" data-fullres-src-type="image/jpeg" />
        <object data-attachment="_SaferoomTestDOC.doc" type="application/msword" data="https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/me/notes/resources/0-07e77c13690247e88afcd20af3b45a12!1-6481EB8A1188E91C!389/$value" />
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Now if I want to replace the image above (`<img>`) I do like this:

```
 {
'target':'img:{cfaf2831-c9e3-4b68-99ac-c4fc0bac0937}{42}',
'action':'replace',
'content':'<img src="NEW IMAGE" alt="NEW IMAGE" />'
```

},

But how do I replace the object which in  my case is a PDF or Word document?
And how do I replace the whole `<body>`?

P.S. I've tried wrapping `<object>` object tags into divs, the `<div>` tags are stripped on upload.

P.P.S. I always need to replace the whole content inside the body and all the objects and images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > But how do I replace the object which in my case is a PDF or Word document? And how do I replace the whole ?

In this scenario, we can delete the old page and create a new one. Here is an sample to create a page with a word and image embed in the page:

```
POST https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/me/notes/pages
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=-------------------------acebdf13572468
Authorization: Bearer {token}

---------------------------acebdf13572468
Content-Disposition:form-data; name="Presentation"
Content-Type:text/html
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>A page with rendered images and an attached file</title>
    <meta name="created" content="2016-05-30T07:30:00-08:00" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Here's an image from an <i>online source</i>:</p>
    <img src="http://png-4.findicons.com/files/icons/2795/office_2013_hd/2000/onenote.png" alt="an image on the page" width="500" />
    <p>Here's an image uploaded as <b>binary data</b>:</p>
    <img src="name:imageBlock1" alt="an image on the page" width="300" />
    <p>Here's a file attachment:</p>
    <object data-attachment="doc1.docx" data="name:fileBlock1" type="application/docx" />
  </body>
</html>
```

```
---------------------------acebdf13572468
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="imageBlock1"; filename="wdIcon.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

<@INCLUDE *C:\users\username\desktop\wdIcon.jpg*@>
---------------------------acebdf13572468
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="fileBlock1"; filename="doc1.docx"
Content-Type: application/msword

<@INCLUDE *C:\users\username\desktop\doc1.docx*@>
---------------------------acebdf13572468—
```

Comment: Hmm..sounds reasonable. In a nutshell my code should work like that:
1. Get current page.
2. Let user edit it the way he wants.
3. Delete the old page.
4. Create a new page with user edits

Then it will change the page id, right? and it means whatever links I had to this page using page id, they will not work from now on?

Comment: It depends on whether you want to the old page content. If you want to create the new page refer to the old page. You can get the current page information and create the new page as you wanted. And if you want to keep the old page, you don't need to delete it. And all the links you made in the new page is available after the page is created.

Answer (score 0):

To replace the whole body (technically only the first immediate child div of the body tag), use:

```
{
 'target':'body',
 'action':'replace',
 'content':'your new page content'
}
```

Comment: I don't think that it is possible. Please check the page : http://dev.onenote.com/docs#/reference/patch-pages/
It says that <body> = first div on the page, which in turn has position:absolute and REPLACE action is not supported for it.